# mesos marathon not sending http callbacks

Tags: mesos, marathon

I have successfully created and run tasks on mesos using marathon. However, marathon is supposed to support http callbacks when you start it using

```
--event_subscriber http_callback --http_endpoints http://myip:3000/endpoints
```

However, this does not seem to actually send any callbacks to my service. Is there anything else that is supposed to be used in order to use the callbacks?

Comment: Hey Justin, in which version of Marathon are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: @ConnorDoyle both v0.2.2 and v0.3.0

Comment: For reference, this is also being discussed in Marathon's issues: https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/issues/148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue stemmed from the fact that I had multiple versions of marathon running. The first version of marathon, which was considered master, was not configured to use callbacks. The second marathon was, which was considered slave, was configured to use callbacks.

As the documentation states, all requests to a slave will be forwarded to the master.